# How can I set Cache TTL for woff and woff2 font files with htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, cache, fonts

My WordPress site htaccess file currently has these entries to set cache expiry for woff and woff2 font files:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Content type
    AddType application/font-woff   .woff
    AddType application/font-woff2  .woff2
    ExpiresActive on
  # Web fonts
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff   "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2  "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

But I'm still getting suggestions to set cache TTL for these files in speed testing tools. Here's one example with a cache efficiency problem: https://gtmetrix.com/reports/bydik.com/ad8hZTzh/

[image]

Is there anything wrong with my htaccess file? How can I solve this?

Comment: To clarify, you are serving these font files directly from your server?

Comment: Yes. They are served directly from my server.

Comment: Are you using a CDN? "cache TTL" - Does the suggestion really state "TTL" (Time-To-Live)? TTL is a DNS/CDN term.

Comment: Here's the result I'm talking about- https://tools.keycdn.com/speed?h=5fd3449203b8e4746a0abdc2 ... Please see the first two URL of "Efficient cache policy" section.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ExpiresByType font/woff2  "access plus 1 year"
> ExpiresByType application/font-woff2  "access plus 1 year"
> ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff2  "access plus 1 year"
> ```

You need to set `ExpiresActive On` (at the top) for these directives to have any effect.

You also don't need all 3 of these directives. You should check the `Content-Type` HTTP response header for the mime-type your server is sending with this resource - it can only be one. The mime-type needs to match the response from your server.

To determine whether these directives are working or not, you should check for the `Expires` and `Cache-Control: max-age` headers in the HTTP response.

**UPDATE:** You are using a CDN (Cloudflare), so ultimately the cache response headers are going to be determined by the CDN.

You are serving two font files:

1. `https://example.com/libs/fonts/fontsolaimanlipi.woff`
2. `https://example.com/fonts/fontawesome.woff2`

The first is a `woff` font file (not woff2) and is sent with a `application/x-font-woff` mime-type (so the above directives would need to be modified for this).

The second is not sending a `Content-Type` header at all (so the above directives will not apply, unless you have an `ExpiresDefault` directive?), so maybe your server is not enabled for this mime type. For example:

```
AddType font/woff2 .woff2
```

Or maybe this can be configured in the CDN.

Comment: "ExpiresActive On" is on my htaccess and there was just one line (application/font-woff2) previously. I've added the other two later to solve the issue.

Comment: What are the actual headers in the HTTP response?

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: I've updated my question with new details.

Comment: The HTTP response doesn't appear to have changed and it's coming from `Server: cloudflare` - so it's possible we are just seeing a cached response from Cloudflare? This maybe something that needs "fixing" at Cloudflare.